# Traversing a binary tree using linked list

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, linked-list, binary-tree

I am trying to do a preorder traversal of binary tree using a linked list.

```
class BTNode:
"""A node in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self: 'BTNode', item: object, 
             left: 'BTNode' =None, right: 'BTNode' =None) -> None:

        self.item, self.left, self.right = item, left, right


class LLNode:
    """A node in a linked list."""

    def __init__(self: 'LLNode', item: object, link: 'LLNode' =None) -> None:

        self.item, self.link = item, link

    def __str__(self: 'LLNode') -> str:
        """Return an informative string showing self

        >>> b = LLNode(1, LLNode(2, LLNode(3)))
        >>> str(b)
        '1 -> 2 -> 3'
        """
        return str(self.item) + (' -> ' + str(self.link) if self.link else '')




def preorder(root: BTNode) -> LLNode:
    """Return the first node in a linked list that contains every value from the
    binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an preorder traversal.

    >>> b = BTNode(1, BTNode(2), BTNode(3))
    >>> repr(preorder(b))
   'LLNode(1, LLNode(2, LLNode(3)))'
   >>> b2 = BTNode(4, BTNode(5))
   >>> b3 = BTNode(7, b, b2)
   >>> str(preorder(b3))
   '7 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5'
    """

    return _preorder(root)[0]

def _preorder(root: BTNode) -> (LLNode, LLNode):
    """Return the first and last nodes in a linked list that contains every
    value from the binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an preorder
    traversal.
    """

    if not root:
        return None, None

    left_head, left_tail = _preorder(root.left)

    right_head, right_tail = _preorder(root.right)

    # change from right_tail = left_tail to right_tail = left_head
    if not right_tail:
        right_tail = left_head

    if not left_head:
        left_head = right_head

    if left_tail:
        left_tail.link = right_head

    root_node = LLNode(root.item, left_head)

    return root_node, right_tail
```

I am always getting '7 -> 1 -> 2' instead of '7 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5' as my output in preorder function. I am not quite sure why. Could someone please tell me how I can edit my current code to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an error in your *preorder* code dealing with returns like `LLNode(value, None)`.

Specifically, when you are traversing `BTNode(a, BTNode(b), BTNode(c))` where neither `b` nor `c` has children, you don't merge correctly. You'll want to have another look at your logic for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned the tail of the list properly.  I added some debugging instrumentation to trace the operation of **_preorder** -- which is something *you* should do before posting here.  Debugging is a critical skill.

```
indent = ""
def _preorder(root: BTNode) -> (LLNode, LLNode):
    """Return the first and last nodes in a linked list that contains every
    value from the binary tree rooted at root, listed according to an preorder
    traversal.
    """
    global indent
    print(indent, "  ENTER", root.item if root else "NULL")

    if not root:
        return None, None

    indent += "  "
    left_head, left_tail = _preorder(root.left)
    print (indent, root.item, "Left ", left_head, left_tail, str(left_head))
    right_head, right_tail = _preorder(root.right)
    print (indent, root.item, "Right", right_head, right_tail, str(right_head))

    if not right_tail:
        right_tail = left_tail

    if not left_head:
        left_head = right_head

    if left_tail:
        left_tail.link = right_head

    root_node = LLNode(root.item, left_head)

    print (indent, "LEAVE", root.item, right_tail.item if right_tail else "NULL")
    indent = indent[2:]
    return root_node, right_tail
```

Output for the full traversal is below.  You can see that you never link in the right side properly; I'll leave the repair as an exercise for the student.  :-)

```
   ENTER 7
     ENTER 1
       ENTER 2
         ENTER NULL
       2 Left  None None None
         ENTER NULL
       2 Right None None None
       LEAVE 2 NULL
     1 Left  2 None 2
       ENTER 3
         ENTER NULL
       3 Left  None None None
         ENTER NULL
       3 Right None None None
       LEAVE 3 NULL
     1 Right 3 None 3
     LEAVE 1 NULL
   7 Left  1 -> 2 None 1 -> 2
     ENTER 4
       ENTER 5
         ENTER NULL
       5 Left  None None None
         ENTER NULL
       5 Right None None None
       LEAVE 5 NULL
     4 Left  5 None 5
       ENTER NULL
     4 Right None None None
     LEAVE 4 NULL
   7 Right 4 -> 5 None 4 -> 5
   LEAVE 7 NULL

Main: 7 -> 1 -> 2
```

---

**RESPONSE TO OP UPDATE**

Obviously, that fixed part of your problem.  Now, let's look at what happens when you return from the calls for node 1's left and right subtrees, and try to link those properly into the linear list:

```
left_head, left_tail = _preorder(root.left)
# returns 2, None
right_head, right_tail = _preorder(root.right)
# returns 3, None

if not right_tail:
    right_tail = left_head
# right_tail is now node 2; this isn't correct: node 3 should be in that spot.

if not left_head:
# left_head is node 2; not an issue now

if left_tail:
# left_tail is None; not an issue now

return root_node, right_tail
# You return nodes 1 and 2;
#   you never linked node 2 to node 3.
# You need to fix this.
```

Comment: Thanks for the debugging. However, I am not sure which part of code is not properly linking the right side. Do I need to add an extra if condition or edit one of my current if conditions? I am really confused.

Comment: At the moment, you need to find a debugging technique that works for you.  For instance, draw your tree on paper.  Work through the calls, one statement at a time, until you have the left-most subtree properly linked; that's 7->1->2.  Now, back up one level and paper-trace through the right subtree, 3.  Write down variable values and examine how the code *actually* works, finding the spot where you get **None**, but you expected to link to node **3**.

Comment: I changed my if condition that checks whether there is a right tail. Please look at the edited version. Now I am getting '7 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5' but Im not sure why the 3 is not being included

Comment: I see now. Node 3 is never being linked to Node 2. Would I have to do left_head.link = right head when there is no right tail?

Comment: I'm not sure what your *intended* logic is; you didn't explain how you expect this to work.  **left_head.link = right_head** would link node 2 directly to node 3; what happens when you try that?  What would happen if node 2 had children?  Yes, those are leading questions.

Comment: Can you tell me whether my 'if not right_tail:' condition is fine or do I need to add an extra condition in the function?

Comment: It looks fine.  Again, I can't tell for sure, since you *still* haven't explained your intended logic.

Comment: What I *can* see from the tracing **print** statements is that your final stage (pasting together the children of node 7) won't work.  Even if node 3 is linked in after node 2, you'll drop that and link node 2 directly to node 4, leaving link 3 (and anything else is a larger tree) in the garbage.

Comment: You need to walk to the *end* of the left side and set *that* node's **.link** to be the right side.  At the moment, you go down only one level, changing **left_head.link**, regardless of the value it had at the time.

Comment: What should I do? This is due tonight for me and I am not quite sure how to fix it.

Comment: Since you're apparently unable to describe your design, unable to desk-check your program, and unable to work through the suggestions I've given, all I can suggest is to find someone nearby to give you 15-30 minutes of tutoring to walk you through these programming skills.  I'm not going to repair your design and hand you the solution; you learn very little from that, and you're already in enough confusion.  You're very close, but you *really* need those individual skills to get into even harder problems.